# Can I set a preferred transportation method in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Every time I start a new search in Google Maps for directions, the default transportation method is always self-driving, and I need to change it to public transportation or walking.

Can I set a preferred transportation method in Google Maps?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the web app I suggest using the mobile app so that you can follow your trip as you go.

Once you select a transport method in iOS 10, it continues to default to that option even when closing and re-opening the app. I'm assuming Android has the same behavior.

Comment: If you were referring to the mobile app, please clarify which OS and it can be migrated.